# Python / Tensorflow 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' on yolov3 model

Tags: python, numpy, object, keras, yolo

I have the following code which uses TensorFlow. After I reshape a list, it says

```
'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

when I try to print its shape.

```
image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
feature_batch = train_model(image_batch)
print(feature_batch.shape)
```

my code for yolov3 model

```
# define the model
model = make_yolov3_model()

# load the model weights
# I have loaded the pretrained weights in a separate dataset
weight_reader = WeightReader('yolov3.weights')

# set the model weights into the model
weight_reader.load_weights(model)

# save the model to file
model.save('model.h5')
```

```
# load yolov3 model
from keras.models import load_model
train_model = load_model('model.h5', compile=False)
```

**Output**

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4412\2773113981.py in <module>
> 1 image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
> 2 feature_batch = train_model(image_batch)
> ----> 3 print(feature_batch.shape)
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Could anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a (python) `list`, a `numpy` `array`, and a `tensor`?  In this case you may need to learn more about `train_model` and what it produces.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"` occurs when we try to access the shape attribute on a list.

Lists do not have any attribute name shape.

To solve this error, pass the list to the `numpy.array()` method to create a numpy array before accessing the shape attribute.

So, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
feature_batch=np.array(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch.shape)
```

Comment: what is the error?